# Google Drive SDK error when uploading icons

Tags: google-drive-api

When trying to upload an application icon on the Google Drive SDK, the pop up box says:

> There was an error! Details: Invalid credentials (missing or invalid
>   oAuth token)

I have tried logging in and out, and using a different browser, but it keeps happening. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060961/google-apps-marketplace-sdk-invalid-credentials-missing-or-invalid-oauth-token/22141399#22141399